# Expo/Supabase app receives a Network request failed error after a while

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, supabase

I have built an app with Supabase and Expo (React Native). The app works well and everything is fine. However, After I leave the app open for a while, I get an error which is difficult to track. It says `TypeError: Network Request failed`.
There is not much in the error to explain where to look for the error.
However, it might have something to do with the session or requests that are being made to Supabase. They are casual requests and fetches. It definitely seems to be related to `ios` platform. I'll put `eas.json` and `app.json` files here as well.
I looked around for a similar situation but could not find one on StackOverflow or online.

`Error:`

```
Object {
  "code": "",
  "details": "TypeError: Network request failed
    at anonymous (http://10.0.0.80:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:6693:33)
    at apply (native)
    at anonymous (http://10.0.0.80:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:39719:26)
    at _callTimer (http://10.0.0.80:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:39630:17)
    at callTimers (http://10.0.0.80:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:39838:19)
    at apply (native)
    at __callFunction (http://10.0.0.80:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:3732:36)
    at anonymous (http://10.0.0.80:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:3452:31)
    at __guard (http://10.0.0.80:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:3669:15)
    at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://10.0.0.80:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:3451:21)",
  "hint": "",
  "message": "TypeError: Network request failed",
}
```

Here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "invoice-generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Generate invoices, estimates, PTOs on the go and send them to clients with a couple of taps",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.30.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.32.0",
    "base64-arraybuffer": "^1.0.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.6",
    "expo-checkbox": "^2.4.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.3",
    "expo-font": "^11.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-location": "^16.1.0",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-print": "~12.4.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "^12.3.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.5.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "^0.18.11",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.72.3",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.13.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here's my `App.tsx`

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'
import { supabase } from './lib/supabase'
import Auth from './components/account/Auth'
import { Session } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import Navigation from './components/general/Navigation'
import { StripeProvider } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native'
import { SessionContext } from './components/general/SessionContext'

export default function App() {
  const [session, setSession] = useState<Session | null>(null)
  const [user, setUser] = useState<object | null>(null)
  const [isSessionSet, setIsSessionSet] = useState(false) // Add this state

  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setSession(session);
      if (session) {
        setUser(session.user);
        setIsSessionSet(true); // Mark session as set
      } else {
        setUser(null); // Clear user if session is not available
        setIsSessionSet(false); // Mark session as not set
      }
    });
  
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_event, session) => {
      setSession(session);
      if (session) {
        setUser(session.user);
        setIsSessionSet(true); // Mark session as set
      } else {
        setUser(null); // Clear user if session is not available
        setIsSessionSet(false); // Mark session as not set
      }
    });
  }, []);
  

  return (
    <StripeProvider publishableKey='pk_test_51HhPuUK1omnuMJYrNMXx9TZgm4MhtRewC2QU8WTBBcHUTBUFshVHc3HCI7xXoPwjUC8asvr03tz9hLOWBRUXasSy00uLZxpufi'>
      <SessionContext.Provider value={user}>
        {isSessionSet && session && session.user ? <Navigation /> : <Auth />}
      </SessionContext.Provider>
    </StripeProvider>
  )
}
```

Here's my `eas.json`

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.7.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "serviceAccountKeyPath": "/Users/user/Documents/pc-api-7163861791138918547-797-b43a882d1b83.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Invoice Generator",
    "slug": "invoice-generator",
    "version": "1.0.20",
    "description": "Generate invoices, estimates, PTOs on the go and send them to clients with a couple of taps",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.shashankaf.invoicegenerator",
      "buildNumber": "20" 
    },
    "android": {
      "versionCode": "20",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.shashankaf.invoicegenerator"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "bdc81d5d-1868-47c5-8980-27a64b950d1e"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/bdc81d5d-1868-47c5-8980-27a64b950d1e"
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have an idea where this error is coming from
Best

I was expecting the app to work normal as it does until a certain time is passed. In production, it gives me a blank screen, totally white.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that everything was the excessive storage issue, somehow using multiple `useEffects` in components caused lots of memory usage. After unifying the `useEffects` and making the actions async, the memory issue disappeared and the app does not seem to go blank.
React has this issue of re-rendering.